# req when posted in Express and req.body when posted from Angular and how to reconcile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following code:

Module1.js

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
     var answer = req.body.key;//this is already declared and works 
//just fine when sent from Angular but this is undefined when sent from
//express


     function something(){console.log(answer)}
}
```

Module2:

```
var confusing = require('../Module1Directory/Module1.js');

exports.create = function(req, res){
      var req = {key: value}
      confusing.create(req, res).something();//this is undefined
}
```

When I post using $http from Angular req.body = {key: value}
When I post from Express req = {key: value} and req.body = *undefined*
How do I deal with this difference or what did I miss?

To be clear, I wrote lots of code declaring variables with the req.body format and changing variables now to req only would be very tricky and time consuming as would be porting code between modules (and there'd be all sorts of messy redundancy).

Comment: Is anyone out there? Thanks for the help thus far, I've spent a lot of time figuring out something simple but yet not explained in a generally applicable way through any tutorial I've seen. I think I'm on the last step and trying to get this to work is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefine req in second module.

```
var req = {key: value};
```

Use this instead (obviously this is a bad approach; you wouldn't overwrite the request body if you want grant maintainability):

```
var req = { body: { key: value } };
```

Comment: Why is it different posting from Angular than posting from Express?

Comment: Because when Angular posts to an url, express populate the request body itself with the body parser. If you do this manually, you have to simulate this in order to have the same result.